# The name 'Articles' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In the main.dart folder "The name 'Articles' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument." and "Undefined name 'NewsService'." i am getting the error how can i fix it

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Articles> articles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    NewsService.getNews().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        articles = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just copied and pasted a snippet of code without all the context required for it to work.

You should add an `Articles` object in your project and import it in your current file.
You should also have a `NewsService` class, with the `getNews` method in your project.